# Google Drive HTTP 403 "Access Not Configured" error with DrEdit

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm attempting to install the DrEdit sample app for python onto GAE. The app runs, but saving or opening a file results in an **HTTP 403 "Access Not Configured Error"**.

**client.json** has **client_id** and **client_secret** set per the **API Access>Client ID for Drive SDK values**. I have also attempted to use the values for **API Access>Client ID for web applications**.

The **Google Drive SDK> OAuth Client ID** has also been set variously to the Drive SDK and web app Client IDs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362853/google-drive-authentication-issues

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the services section of the Google API console there are two services relating to drive development, SDK and API. When you create a new Drive SDK entry, Drive API service is not automatically enabled (which doesn't make sense, I don't see when you'd create a drive enabled application without using the drive API). Switch the Drive API service on for  the project and try again.

@lurking_googlers I think a lot of people will fall for this, doesn't it make sense to enable the API  when the SDK is enabled?

Comment: We'll see if we can auto-enable Drive API.  This is a good find, we'll make sure to document it better.

Comment: Thanks, David. Unfortunately I'd already set **"Drive SDK"** to **"On"** during my debugging, to no avail.

Comment: No, not Drive SDK, Drive _API_. Both must be on.

Comment: Duh. That worked. Thanks! You're right, the UI is somewhat confusing.

Comment: !!! I spent over 50 hours at work this week trying to make Google Drive work with our app, and it all comes down to a a stupid hidden checkbox!? I can't thank you enough for saving me from wasting another 50+ hours trying to figure it out!

Comment: My God, I have spent two days solving that before deciding to google for error message.

Comment: I almost killed myself.

Comment: Url to enable apis and much more (I'm sure you all know it) https://cloud.google.com/console

Answer (score -1):

And your must also identify in your code the following

```
DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive
```

good luck