# Assertion failure in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble uploading a file to Google Drive. I carefully followed the instructions and I'm able to login and authenticate a user, but when I go to upload a file I am hit with the following assertion:

> *** Assertion failure in -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:], /Users/.../google-api-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m:399

I double checked and made sure that -ObjC -all_load is in Other Linker Flags.

Here is the code I'm using, which is basically just a copy of what Google is using in their sample.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *localPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                      localPath,fileNameString];

NSData *myFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
file.title = fileNameString;
file.descriptionProperty = fileNameString;
file.mimeType = @"application/pdf";

GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters
                                         uploadParametersWithData:myFileData
                                         MIMEType:@"application/pdf"];

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                  GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                  NSError *error) {
                  if (error == nil) {
                      NSLog(@"file uploaded");
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"upload failed");            
                  }
              }];
```

Here is the code that is highlighted when the assertion occurs:

```
  // The initial response of the resumable upload protocol should have an
  // empty body
  //
  // This assert typically happens because the upload create/edit link URL was
  // not supplied with the request, and the server is thus expecting a non-
  // resumable request/response.
  NSAssert([[self downloadedData] length] == 0,
                    @"unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)");
```

Does anyone know what URL they are referring to? I haven't seen a URL being used for uploading a new file anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. You need to enable Drive API and Drive SDK from the API Console/Services tab. Here's the post that helped:

[Google Drive HTTP 403 "Access Not Configured" error with DrEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368678/google-drive-http-403-access-not-configured-error-with-dredit)